# Android: how to enumerate available DRM plugins

Tags: android, api, drm

I need to collect information on all available DRM plugins. Android's [document on DRM](https://source.android.com/devices/drm.html) mentions that all available plugins can be found under `/system/lib/drm/plugins/native/`.  Is there an API that can give me similar information in a more friendly format (e.g. human readable plugin names rather than cryptic filenames).

Comment: Have you looked at the DRM api documentation yet? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html

Comment: I did.  Is there something specific to my question that I may have missed?

Comment: Well, you just said you needed to collect information on all available DRM plugins...the DrmManagerClient has methods like acquireDrmInfo() and processDrmInfo() that can give you the...information. What information do you need exactly that the API can't handle?

Comment: These methods, as far as I understand from the docs, are called on a particular DRM system.  I still need an API that enumerates all available DRMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrmManagerClient.getAvailableDrmEngines() gives you the info of all the available engines.

There's no reason to read these from the file location yourself. From the [DRM docs](https://source.android.com/devices/drm.html)

> Plug-ins are loaded automatically when DrmManagerService is launched

Comment: Ah, missed that one.  Thanks.